# React leaflet 'offline' does not exist on type 'typeof tileLayer'

Tags: typescript, import, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to implement an offline map with leaflet.offline using this article as a guide https://walkingtreetech.medium.com/play-with-maps-in-react-online-and-offline-using-leaflet-libraries-3383ea200898 but I keep on getting this error: `Property 'offline' does not exist on type 'typeof tileLayer'`.

The code I try to run is:

```
const map = L.map('map-id');
const offlineLayer = L.tileLayer.offline('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', localforage, {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        subdomains: 'abc',
        minZoom: 13,
        maxZoom: 19,
        crossOrigin: true
    });
offlineLayer.addTo(map);//add the offline layer
map.zoomControl.remove();
```

The dependencies in the package.json are:

```
"leaflet": "1.7.1",
"leaflet.markercluster": "1.4.1",
"leaflet.offline": "^2.2.0",
"localforage": "^1.10.0",
```

Comment: same issue in ionic/angular! found anything?